# C: array sum using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sum

How could I get the sum of an array using only pointers ?

```
int array_sum(int *begin, int *end)
{
    int arraysum = 0;
    int *p = 0;
    for (p = begin; p < end; p ++)
    {
        arraysum += *(arr + p);
    } 

   return arraysum;
}
```

this doesn't compile at line

```
arraysum += *(arr + p);
```

Comment: Why do you add `arr` and `p`? Just use `*p`.

Comment: So that I can get arr[p] ?

Comment: This only works if you're iterating over indicies which you aren't. You're iterating over the memory-locations of the array, so `p` always points to the current number.

Comment: I tried using *p and it worked. Please could you explain how ?

Comment: I see. So *p = *(begin + (interation number)) ?

Comment: What is `arr` ?

Comment: arr is an array containing 10 elements (from 1 to 10) which is declared before

Comment: I dont understand how the loop is incremented. we get at first p = begin (adress number) right ? What does it exactly do at p ++ ? It does p + 1 right ? but adresses of int are of size 4 ???

Comment: You need to post all the code. How is the function called? What is `arr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
int array_sum(int *begin, int *end)
{
    int arraysum = 0;
    while (begin < end)
    {
        arraysum += *begin;
        ++begin;
    }
    return arraysum;
}
```

Comment: Ah YES ! I perfectly understand this

Answer (score 0):

```
for (p = begin; p < end; p ++)
{
    arraysum += *(arr + p);
}
```

This doesn't work because you can't add `arr` and `p`. You don't need to add anything to `p`, your number is in `*p`.

As to why: When you iterate over indicies, i.e. `0` to `arraylength - 1`, you always use the *begin* pointer and add the index to it to find you number. In your loop however, you copy the beginning pointer to `p` and increment `P` directly, so `p` starts at the first number, once incremented points at the second number, and so on, until `p` and `end` are the same, note the `p < end` as condition.

> dont understand how the loop is incremented. we get at first p = begin
>   (adress number) right ? What does it exactly do at p ++ ? It does p +
>   1 right ? but adresses of int are of size 4 ???

Pointer-Arithmetic makes this possible. Math on pointers works a bit different, essentially making sure that you add/subtract *multiples* of the objects size. So adding one to your int-pointer actually adds `sizeof(int)` under the hood. This is also how array-indicies work, `array[i]` is equivalent to `*(array + i)`.