# C : reverse array using pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reverse

I don't see where I have made an error in this code :

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
int temp = *a;

*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}

void array_reverse(int *begin, int *end)
{
    int *end2 = end;
    int *q = 0;
    for (q = begin; q < end; q += 1)
    { 
        swap(q, end2); 
        end2 -= 1;
    }
}
```

it should reverse the array:

```
arr{ 1, 2, 3}
```

becomes:

```
arr{ 3, 2, 1}
```

My output:

```
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]
```

becomes :

```
[111009824,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]
```

(well actually this first element always changes each time I compile and test my function and gives me random values I guess )

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Yes i know this, but then why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420928/c-array-sum-using-pointers we do p ++ it's the same ?

Comment: If you don't stop in the middle of the array, you'll reverse it twice and end up where you started.

Comment: How can I stop in the middle of the array please

Comment: pre-decrement `end2` cos at first it points to invalid data

Comment: You can stop in the middle with `q < end2` instead of `q < end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the for loop

```
void array_reverse(int *begin, int *end)
{
    int *end2 = end;
    int *q = 0;
    for (q = begin; q < end; q += 1)
    { 
        swap(q, end2); 
        end2 -= 1;
    }
}
```

You must change `end` to `end2` in order to stop when you reach the middle 
You must also decrement end2 before you call swap so you are pointing at the right value

```
void array_reverse(int *begin, int *end)
{
    int *end2 = end;
    int *q = 0;
    for (q = begin; q < end2; q += 1)
    { 
        end2 -= 1;
        swap(q, end2); 

    }
}
```

The function call would then look something like this

```
int test[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
array_reverse(test, test + 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems. In the `for` loop, `end` should have been `end2`.

```
for (q = begin; q < end2; q += 1) {
    swap(q, end2); 
    end2 -= 1; }
```

The other issue was the call. It should have been `array_reverse (a, a+9);` because `array` indexes start at `0`. Giving `a+10` for the second argument with an `array` of length 10 passes a pointer to nonsense outside the array bounds.

I must express some appreciation for the question, it got me researching the fundamental difference between "swapping pointer addresses around" and swapping the "data to which the pointers point.

Something else worth noting is that, in C, *[function arguments are by-value copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)*. We could rewrite `array_reverse` like this with no adverse consequences. Why does this work?

```
void array_reverse(int *begin, int *end)
    for ( ;begin < end; ) swap(begin++, end--)
```

The function body receives *local copies* of arguments to work on. Hence, there is nothing wrong with modifying their values. It is *guaranteed* that the function can't modify the initial values of its arguments outside the function without simulating a pass by reference through some form of [indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indirection). There is a powerful simplicity to grasping the concept.

Answer (score -4):

Here is another way of writing the loop using `while`.

```
void array_reverse(int *first, int *last)
{
    int *f = first;
    int *l = last;
    while (f < l)
    { 
        swap(f, l);
        f++, l--;
    }
}
```